# How to compress the blob file (binary) by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, gzip

I try to compress blob data by usign JavaScript with node-gzip and write the following.

fileblobA data is blob data(binary)

```
const fileblobA = new Blob([result],{type:'application/octet-stream'})
const { gzip, ungzip } = require('node-gzip');
const gzipA = await gzip(fileblobA.arrayBuffer) ;
```

It shows *Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Failed to execute 'arrayBuffer' on 'Blob': Illegal invocation*

I would like to know how to fix it.

Comment: What is `fileBlobA` and where does it come from?  Can you show the code that generates that?  The error message implies that `fileBlobA.arrayBuffer` does not exist.

Comment: I added the flieblobA where does it come from. I found Node.js 14.16 that I use is not compatible blob.arrayBuffer.